Reactjs : I want to have inline validation error using yup when maxlimit is exceeded in text field
I am trying to have a text-field in a formik form with a max-limit(250 characters) property. I want to display an inline validation error when the user tries to enter 251th character. I am using Yup for validation.
Problem is that with the maxlength property , it will never let me write the 251th character to trigger the error.
inputProps={{
               maxLength: 250,
            }}

My Yup schema looks like this :
 const descriptionValidation = Yup.string()
    .max(250, 'Description cannot exceed 250 characters')
    .optional();

I tried having 251 as a max limit and triggering field touch on the enter of last character , but it comes with 2 problems :

It takes an extra character than required (we can remove that charater on submit but i think that's too cumbersome)
Yup validation is only triggered when i focus out from the field.
Given is my code for text field :

<Field
                as={TextField}
                name="description"
                label="Description"
                multiline
                rows={4}
                placeholder="Optional"
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true,
                }}
                inputProps={{
                  maxLength: 251,
                }}
                error={Boolean(errors.description && touched.description)}
                helperText={errors.description && touched.description && errors.description}
                onChange={(event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
                  const { value } = event.target;
                  setFieldValue('description', value);
                  if (value.length > 250) {
                    setFieldTouched('description', true);
                    // setFieldValue('description', value.slice(0, 250));
                  }
                }}
              />

So is there way in which this thing can be achieved ?

Since you validate the form with yup, you don't need inputProps.maxLength anymore.

It takes an extra character than required (we can remove that charater on submit but i think that's too cumbersome)

If you get the form values from Formik.onSubmit(), you can rest assure that all the fields are valid. If there is any error when validating the form, Formik.onSubmit() will not being called (the form is not submitting).

Yup validation is only triggered when i focus out from the field

That is not this case. By default, formik will validate every time the field's value is changed. Your code isn't working because touched doesn't get update until the field is blur.
In the following code, I remove the use of inputProps.maxLength and touched. Error will show as soon as the description exceeds 250 characters.
import React from 'react';

import { Form, Formik, Field } from 'formik';

import { Button, TextField } from '@mui/material';

import * as Yup from 'yup';

const FormSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    description: Yup.string()
        .max(250, 'Description cannot exceed 250 characters')
        .optional(),
});

export default function MyForm() {
    return (
        <Formik
            initialValues={{
                description: '',
            }}
            validationSchema={FormSchema}
            onSubmit={values => {
                console.log(values);
            }}
        >
            {({ errors }) => (
                <Form>
                    <Field
                        as={TextField}
                        name='description'
                        label='Description'
                        multiline
                        rows={4}
                        placeholder='Optional'
                        InputLabelProps={{
                            shrink: true,
                        }}
                        error={Boolean(errors.description)}
                        helperText={errors.description}
                    />
                    <Button variant='contained' type='submit'>Submit</Button>
                </Form>
            )}
        </Formik>
    );
};

Reference:

https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation#when-does-validation-run
https://formik.org/docs/tutorial#visited-fields
https://formik.org/docs/examples/instant-feedback

